# hotspot problem

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers, ethernet

[image]my laptops hotspot is on,but doesn't show laptops name in my mobile wifi settings.Any one knows??what the problem is?.

Comment: It's not enabled in the picture. It appears on but on the left column it says it's disconnected. That's happens sometimes when it didn't create a hotspot correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to Network Icon on top panel ->network settings--> Edit Connections from the bottom of the box …, then click the Add button in right bottom corner of pop-up window.
Step 2: Now a popup window appeared with a dropdown box,select wifi from the box and click create.
Step 3:In next window, do:

Type in a connection name. The name will be used later.
Type in a SSID(like hotspot,internet_share etc)
Select mode: Hotspot
Band:automatic 
BSSID: leave blank
Device MAC address: select your wireless card from drop-down menu.
Set MTU: Automatic 
Step 4: choose wifi-security from top of popup window 
     Select security from dropdown box toWPA-WPA2 personal 
Step 5:Then Go to to ipv4 and ipv6 settings abd set method to "shared to other computer "
Thats iT
You will now see an access point name in wifi settings.just click on that then enjoy your laptops internet with other device